# I am getting the error code "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DirectBlock."

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using this code and getting the Error Message "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DirectBlock." At Source: "block = new DirectBlock(lvlArray[i],(i-row*22)*25,row*25);"

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
public class EmptyBlock extends MovieClip{
    private var _root:MovieClip;

    public function EmptyBlock(){
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);
    }
    private function beginClass(e:Event):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);

        this.buttonMode = true;//make this act like a button
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thisClick);
    }
    private function eFrameEvents(e:Event):void{
        if(_root.gameOver){
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thisClick);
            MovieClip(this.parent).removeChild(this);
        }
    }
    private function thisMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void{

        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
    private function thisMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void{

        this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
    private function thisClick(e:MouseEvent):void{

    }
}
    }
```

And this is the .fla file:

```
  stop();

//setting vars to step in for turns and special blocks
var S:String = 'START';
var F:String = 'FINISH';
var U:String = 'UP';
var R:String = 'RIGHT';
var D:String = 'DOWN';
var L:String = 'LEFT';

var startDir:String;
var finDir:String;
var startCoord:int;
var lvlArray:Array = new Array();

lvlArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
            S,D,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,R,1,F,
            0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,R,1,1,U,0,0,R,1,1,U,0,0,R,1,1,U,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            ];

//the names of these variables explain what they do
var currentLvl:int = 1;
var gameOver:Boolean = false;

function startGame():void{
    //right now we don't have any code
}

var roadHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(roadHolder);
function makeRoad():void{
    var row:int = 0;
    var block;//this will act as the block that we're placing down
    for(var i:int=0;i<lvlArray.length;i++){//creating a loop that'll go through the level array
        if(lvlArray[i] == 0){//if the current index is set to 0
            block = new EmptyBlock();//create a gray empty block
            block.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            block.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(block);
            //and set the coordinates to be relative to the place in the array
            block.x= (i-row*22)*25;
            block.y = row*25;
        } else if(lvlArray[i] == 1){//if there is supposed to be a row
            //just add a box that will be a darker color and won't have any actions
            block = new Shape();
            block.graphics.beginFill(0x111111);
            block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            block.graphics.endFill();
            block.x= (i-row*22)*25;
            block.y = row*25;
            roadHolder.addChild(block);//add it to the roadHolder
        } else if(lvlArray[i] is String){block
            //then create a special block
            block = new DirectBlock(lvlArray[i],(i-row*22)*25,row*25);
            addChild(block);
        }
        for(var c:int = 1;c<=16;c++){
            if(i == c*22-1){
                //if 22 columns have gone by, then we move onto the next row
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
}
//run these functions at the start
makeRoad();
startGame();
```

Comment: Where is your DirectBlock class? You do not currently have vision on that. You may need to import it, currently you are getting that error because that class has not been made not available where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course, you got no class called `DirectBlock` and your class `EmptyBlock` has no parameters in the constructor (in case you wanted to use the second class and not the first).